# APT lock contention on multi-stage (parallel) builds with cache

Tags: docker, caching, apt, contention, buildkit

I am using multi-stage build where both stages install APT packages (MWE Dockerfile below). I use `--mount=type=cache` on `/var/cache/apt` to avoid re-downloading of packages, in both stages. The cache directory is shared between the stages, which in itself is good, but: as they run in parallel, one or the other will fail with:

```
43.24 E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock. It is held by process 0
43.24 E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

(the `-o DPkg::Lock::Timeout=180` option would not help, that is for dpkg, not APT)

Now, I see three possible ways to solve this, but don't know how to realize either of them (without hacks, that is):

1. make APT wait for the lock to be released; is there an option for that? I could not duckduck anything out.
2. make the cache separate for each stage; I would not mind, as the packages installed are typically different (build vs. runtime), but don't see an option to `--mount` which would let me specify that.
3. make the build run serially; I really would not mind, that is not the issue. But again, could not find any option for buildkit enforcing that.

Advice or other suggestions would be appreciated.

---

This is a minimal Dockerfile which you can try yourself; it does not do anything useful but should trigger the issue.

```
FROM debian:bookworm-20230919 as builder
RUN rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt apt update && apt -y --no-install-recommends install build-essential
# build stuff, result in /tmp/build


FROM debian:bookworm-20230919 as production
RUN rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/var/cache/apt apt update && apt -y --no-install-recommends install vim
# install stuff via --mount=target=/build,from=builder,source=/tmp/build
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit the sharing setting of a cache mount for situations like this:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,sharing=locked,target=/var/cache/apt apt update && apt -y --no-install-recommends install build-essential
```

> `sharing`: One of `shared`, `private`, or `locked`. Defaults to `shared`. A `shared` cache mount can be used concurrently by multiple writers. `private` creates a new mount if there are multiple writers. `locked` pauses the second writer until the first one releases the mount.

https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#run---mount

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed! :) Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about copying the content across from one stage to the other?

```
FROM debian:bookworm-20230919 as builder

RUN rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean
RUN apt update && apt -y --no-install-recommends install build-essential

FROM debian:bookworm-20230919 as production

COPY --from=builder /var/cache/apt/ /var/cache/apt/
COPY --from=builder /var/lib/apt/lists/ /var/lib/apt/lists/

RUN apt -y --no-install-recommends install vim
```

This will force the stages to build serially, but you say you're okay with that.

By copying across the cache and package lists you don't need to run `apt update` in the `production` stage. I'm assuming that this was the goal with caching `/var/cache/apt/` between stages?

Comment: Thank you; that was not really the goal; that was to cache downloaded APT archives across builds (there will be just a few common packages between the two stages).